# Can I run a script that is stored inside an apk?

Tags: java, android

So currently I have an app that runs shell scripts that I have stored in /system/bin
That works great.

But, what I want to do is have my app run the exact same shell script except run it from the raw directory. ( Or any other directory that is internal to the apk)

This is an example of how I call one of my scripts:

```
if (cb8on) try {Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", "mod8"});
    } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace();}
    else   try {Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", "mod8b"});
    } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace();}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is possible. The script is expected on the file system and not within an APK. You can copy it from the APK to the file system and then run it (make sure, the script has execute permission when you copy it).

Comment: So what's the best way to go about it? Define the file then renameTo? And how could I change the permissions to 777?